# Removing the xy axis or Changing the color of the xy axis in a line chart in chart js 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I have a issue in my chart.js code that is I want to remove both the axis lines from the graph, i want the grids to be displayed (NOTE)

`
const MAINCHARTCANVAS = document.querySelector(".main-chart")

new Chart(MAINCHARTCANVAS, {
type: 'line',
data: {
labels: ["Mon" , "Tue" , "Wed" , "Thu" , "Fri" , "Sat" , "Sun"],
datasets: [{
label: 'My First Dataset',
data: [7,5,7,7,8,7,4],
borderColor: "#4F3422",
tension: 0.4,
borderWidth:7,
borderSkipped: true,
}]
},
options: {
scales: {

```
        x:{
            grid:{
                display:false,  
            },
            border:{
                didplay: false,
            }
        },

        y:{
            drawBorder: false, 
            beginAtZero: true,
            grid:{
                lineWidth:3,
                color:"#E8ddd9",
            },
            border: {
                display:false,
                dash: [10,16],
            },
            ticks: {display: false}
        }
    },

    plugins: {
        legend: false, // Hide legend
        tooltip:{
            enabled: false
        },
        backgroundCircle: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
        point:{
            radius: 3
        }
    }
}
```

})
`

this my previous code I had tried

changing color or removing the axis enough for me

[sample img for the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhW4Z.png)

i am expecting like this

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UruWa.png)

Try to change the color of it to transparent or try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your question that you don't want the base line's on the both axis.

so you can do so simply adding below code in your `options`

```
scales: {
      x: {
          display: false, // this false makes whole data of an axis hidden
         },
      y: {
          display: false,
          }
 }
```

and if you want to customise the grid lines, ticks and the dash "-" which is rendering between tick and the base border of the axis you can with following code:

```
grid: {
    color: 'rgba(100, 250, 132, 0.4)', // grid lines color
    drawTicks: false, // this will removes the "-" which is rendered between the tick and the base border
    drawOnChartArea: true, // borders inside the chart area
},
ticks: {
    color: 'red', // color of the tick (make "transparent" if you don't want to show the ticks on the axis)
    display: true, // if you want to hide the tick label (i.e. red, blue etc) make it false
}
```

Hope this code works.

Thanks.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
          x: {
              display: false, // this false makes whole data of an axis hidden
          },
          y: {
              display: false,
          }
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```